# Getting Error "NameError: name 'TLSExtSupportedGroup' is not defined" while executing the program

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, openssl, scapy

I am trying to execute the program `full_rsa_connection_with_application_data.py` given [here](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/blob/master/examples/full_rsa_connection_with_application_data.py). However, I dont know why I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "full_rsa_connection_with_application_data.py", line 21, in <module>
    extensions = [TLSExtension() / TLSExtECPointsFormat(),TLSExtension()/ TLSExtSupportedGroup()]
NameError: name 'TLSExtSupportedGroup' is not defined
```

How can I proceed further?

Comment: Did you `pip install scapy-ssl_tls`?

Comment: Yeah.. I used pip to install it

Comment: can you do a pip freeze?

Answer (score 1):

With pip install you are installing the code of the release 1.2.3.2 so you should try this example instead:

https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/blob/release/1.2.3/examples/full_rsa_connection_with_application_data.py

The example you linked there is working from the master branch at is has classes the release hasnt like TLSExtSupportedGroup